# iPhone NSString convert to readable text

Tags: iphone, nsstring

I have a piece of NSString that will read "Test & Test" or with "

Is there any way without searching and replacing to make that display as "&" or """ ??

Comment: Could you place your strings and/or your result in code blocks as I'm unsure as to what exactly it is you want.

Comment: There isn't really any code....I have an NSSTring that when you NSLog it reads....

"Hello my name is test &amp; test" 
and I want it to read
"Hello my name is test & test" 

as that is what it should be but I am reading from some HTML string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this ?

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] autorelease];

[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.mypage.com/content.html"]]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];

NSHTTPURLResponse* authResponse;
NSError* authError;
NSData * authData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&authResponse error:&authError];      

NSString *authResponseBody = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:authData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSLog(@" Nice Result: %@", authResponseBody);
```

---

Adrian

Comment: Code works but still comes back as...
<title>Tyres 4.3&quot; Round</title>

Comment: Try to open the same page with a web-browser like Firefox and the  choose to see page source. If inside the page source you see the same 
&quot; chars.. then the problem is the page itself. try to set the html page encoding to UTF-8 :)

Comment: Yeah the page is at fault :-(  Thanks

Comment: Well no. If you want to unescape entities like &amp; etc. you can. See my answer for one method how.

Comment: When you give `stringWithFormat:` a constant string with no format arguments, you can just provide the string itself, e.g. `[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://.../"]`.

Answer (score 0):

The html string you read is bad formated.

Try to read as UTF-8 or any other formatting in order to get the correct text from the html you're reading.

Can you actually post the code where you read the NSString from the HTML content ?

Comment: NSString *webpage = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:escapedURL]];

Answer (score 0):

[CFXMLCreateStringByUnescapingEntities](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/CoreFOundation/Reference/CFXMLTreeRef/Reference/reference.html) should do it. Thanks to the magic of [toll free bridging](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CarbonCocoaDoc/Articles/InterchangeableDataTypes.html) you can just use your NSString.